# Magento cart disappears when the position is changed

Tags: php, magento

When i try to change:

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" before="-"    template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/">
```

in app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\checkout.xml

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" before="-" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/">
```

my cart vanish. The caching is off.

Comment: do you have already content on the left side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons are:

1. There's no left structural block (check which template is in use)
2. The left structural block is removed by `<remove name="left"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set name=left.cart_sidebar
And remove name=cart_sidebar